# Convert categorical variables to numeric in R

Tags: r

I have a huge database and I am having many categorical variables.
You can watch it here:

```
> M=data.frame(Type_peau,PEAU_CORPS,SENSIBILITE,IMPERFECTIONS,BRILLANCE ,GRAIN_PEAU,RIDES_VISAGE,ALLERGIES,MAINS,
+              INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE,INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO,INTERET_VACANCES,INTERET_COMPOSITION,DataQuest1,Priorite2,
+              Priorite1,DataQuest4,Age,Nbre_gift,w,Nbre_achat)
> # pour voir s'il y a des données manquantes
> str(M)
'data.frame':   836 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ Type_peau             : Factor w/ 5 levels "","Grasse","Mixte",..: 3 4 5 3 4 3 3 3 2 3 ...
 $ PEAU_CORPS            : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Normale","Sèche",..: 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 ...
 $ SENSIBILITE           : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Aucune","Fréquente",..: 4 4 4 2 4 3 4 2 4 4 ...
 $ IMPERFECTIONS         : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Fréquente",..: 3 4 3 4 3 2 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ BRILLANCE             : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Aucune","Partout",..: 4 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 3 4 ...
 $ GRAIN_PEAU            : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Dilaté","Fin",..: 4 4 4 2 4 2 4 4 2 4 ...
 $ RIDES_VISAGE          : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Aucune","Très visibles",..: 2 2 2 4 4 2 4 2 4 2 ...
 $ ALLERGIES             : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Non","Oui",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ MAINS                 : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Moites","Normales",..: 3 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE: Factor w/ 4 levels "","Beaucoup",..: 2 4 4 4 2 2 2 4 4 2 ...
 $ INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO   : Factor w/ 5 levels "","Beaucoup",..: 2 4 2 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ INTERET_VACANCES      : Factor w/ 6 levels "","À la mer",..: 3 4 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 ...
 $ INTERET_COMPOSITION   : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Beaucoup",..: 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 4 2 ...
 $ DataQuest1            : Factor w/ 4 levels "-20","20-30",..: 4 3 4 4 4 3 3 2 3 2 ...
 $ Priorite2             : Factor w/ 7 levels "éclatante","hydratée",..: 3 1 3 4 3 2 7 1 4 6 ...
 $ Priorite1             : Factor w/ 7 levels "éclatante","hydratée",..: 4 6 1 5 1 6 1 2 6 4 ...
 $ DataQuest4            : Factor w/ 2 levels "nature","urbain": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Age                   : int  32 37 23 44 33 30 43 43 60 31 ...
 $ Nbre_gift             : int  1 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ w                     : num  0.25 0.25 0.5 0.25 0.5 0 0 0 0 0.75 ...
 $ Nbre_achat            : int  3 4 7 3 6 9 22 13 7 16 ...
```

I need to convert all categorical variables to numeric automatically. For example for the variable **Type_peau**, it is :

```
 head(Type_peau)
[1] Mixte   Normale Sèche   Mixte   Normale Mixte  
Levels:  Grasse Mixte Normale Sèche
```

I want it :

```
head(Type_peau)
[1] 2 3 4 2 3 2
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

How can I do that automatically for all categorical variables?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `unclass()` to display numeric values of factor variables :

```
Type_peau<-as.factor(c("Mixte","Normale","Sèche","Mixte","Normale","Mixte"))
Type_peau
unclass(Type_peau)
```

To do so on all categorical variables, you can use `sapply()` :

```
must_convert<-sapply(M,is.factor)       # logical vector telling if a variable needs to be displayed as numeric
M2<-sapply(M[,must_convert],unclass)    # data.frame of all categorical variables now displayed as numeric
out<-cbind(M[,!must_convert],M2)        # complete data.frame with all variables put together
```

EDIT : [A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47922653/2504372) works in one step :

```
out<-data.matrix(M)
```

It only works if your data.frame doesn't contain any character variable though (otherwise, they'll be put to NA).

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you're after `data.matrix`. From the function's description:

> Return the matrix obtained by converting all the variables in a data frame to numeric mode and then binding them together as the columns of a matrix. Factors and ordered factors are replaced by their internal codes.

Example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = letters[1:5],
                   B = LETTERS[1:5],
                   C = month.abb[1:5],
                   D = 1:5)
str(mydf)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ B: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ C: Factor w/ 5 levels "Apr","Feb","Jan",..: 3 2 4 1 5
#  $ D: int  1 2 3 4 5
data.matrix(mydf)
#      A B C D
# [1,] 1 1 3 1
# [2,] 2 2 2 2
# [3,] 3 3 4 3
# [4,] 4 4 1 4
# [5,] 5 5 5 5
```

Replace it all at once with:

```
mydf[] <- data.matrix(mydf)
mydf
#   A B C D
# 1 1 1 3 1
# 2 2 2 2 2
# 3 3 3 4 3
# 4 4 4 1 4
# 5 5 5 5 5
```

---

Of course if you have many more column types, you'll have to decide first how you want to deal with them. For instance, there's the concern that if there's a `character` column, `data.matrix` would result in a column of `NA` values, which is correct. However, the correct concern should be "How would you like to deal with `character` columns?

Here are two options. You can extend the logic similarly for other column types.

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = letters[1:5],
                   B = LETTERS[1:5],
                   C = month.abb[1:5],
                   D = 1:5)
mydf$E <- state.abb[1:5]
str(mydf)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ B: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ C: Factor w/ 5 levels "Apr","Feb","Jan",..: 3 2 4 1 5
#  $ D: int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ E: chr  "AL" "AK" "AZ" "AR" ...

## You want to convert everything to numeric
data.matrix(data.frame(unclass(mydf))) 
#      A B C D E
# [1,] 1 1 3 1 2
# [2,] 2 2 2 2 1
# [3,] 3 3 4 3 4
# [4,] 4 4 1 4 3
# [5,] 5 5 5 5 5

## You only want to convert factors to numeric
mydf[sapply(mydf, is.factor)] <- data.matrix(mydf[sapply(mydf, is.factor)])
mydf
#   A B C D  E
# 1 1 1 3 1 AL
# 2 2 2 2 2 AK
# 3 3 3 4 3 AZ
# 4 4 4 1 4 AR
# 5 5 5 5 5 CA
```

Answer (score 5):

```
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(A = letters[1:5],
                   B = LETTERS[1:5],
                   C = month.abb[1:5],
                   D = 1:5)
glimpse(mydf)

# Observations: 5
# Variables: 4
# $ A <fctr> a, b, c, d, e
# $ B <fctr> A, B, C, D, E
# $ C <fctr> Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May
# $ D <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Using predicate functions in `dplyr`

```
mydf %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric)

#  A B C D
# 1 1 1 3 1
# 2 2 2 2 2
# 3 3 3 4 3
# 4 4 4 1 4
# 5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 4):

`as.numeric` does the job too.

```
df <- iris
df$newgroup <- as.factor(rep(c(letters[1:10]))) # just another factor
str(df) # Species and newgroup are categorial variables

as.numeric(df$Species) # this returns the levels (numeric) of Species.
                       # Now, we want to apply this automatically to all
                       # categorical variables

# using lapply
i <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[i] <- lapply(df[i], as.numeric)
str(df)

# using dplyr
#(load df again)
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric)
str(df2)

# using purrr
library(purrr)
df3 <- df %>% map_if(is.factor, as.numeric)
str(df3)
```

If you also want to create dummies variables, try

```
library(dummies)
df.4 <- dummy.data.frame(df, sep = ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answers already posted, this [link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/solved-recode-variable-from-text-to-numbers/10580/8) provides examples of how to convert categorical data to numeric but also map those numbers to specified values if you are not happy with the default conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one single step as well using factor function.

```
M$colname = factor(M$colname, levels = c(level1,level2,...), labels = c(label1, label2,...))
```

**Note: It will replace the column.**

Answer (score 0):

The best and fastest way to do this is by using the code below:

```
DataFrameYouWant <- data.frame(yourData)
DataFrameYouWant[] <- lapply(DataFrameYouWant, as.integer)
```

Code above automatically converts all the factor variables in your data to numeric and your data to a data frame. You can specify which columns/variables you want to convert to numeric.