# about dummy variables in r

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am new to the R language, for my assignment, I am trying to generate several levels dummies for different variables(total in 3). however, each approach i got problem:

method1: followed by https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/coding-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-models/
The code:

```
> housing_prices2$Fuel.Type.f <- factor(housing_prices2$Fuel.Type)
> is.factor(housing_prices2$Fuel.Type.f)
[1] TRUE
> housing_prices2$Fuel.Type.f[1:10]
 [1] Electric Gas      Gas      Gas      Gas      Gas      Oil     
 [8] Oil      Electric Gas     
Levels: Electric Gas None Oil Solar Unknown/Other Wood
```

works well. However, when I got problem in next line:

```
> summary(lm(write ~ Fuel.Type.f, data = housing_prices2))  
Error in model.frame.default(formula = write ~ Fuel.Type.f, data = housing_prices2,:          object is not a matrix
```

I just have no idea about this error and it doesn't make sense to me, so I decided to use another method;

method2: followed by [Convert categorical variables to numeric in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922184/convert-categorical-variables-to-numeric-in-r)

for variable Fuel.Type, it works well:

```
> Fuel.Type <- as.factor(c("Electric", "Gas", "None", "Oil", "Solar", "Unknown/Other",
+                          "Wood"))
> Fuel.Type
[1] Electric      Gas           None          Oil           Solar        
[6] Unknown/Other Wood         
Levels: Electric Gas None Oil Solar Unknown/Other Wood
> unclass(Fuel.Type)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
attr(,"levels")
[1] "Electric"      "Gas"           "None"          "Oil"          
[5] "Solar"         "Unknown/Other" "Wood"
```

but when I try to generate dummies for other variables,  then i got this error:

```
> housing_prices2$Heat.Type.f[1:10]
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Heat.Type.f'.
```

I have clueless about what's going on about these error either...
any suggestions are appreciated!

BTW, here is my sample data table:

```
>$ Fuel.Type    : chr  "Electric" "Gas" "Gas" "Gas"

>$ Heat.Type    : chr  "Electric" "Hot Water" "Hot Water" "Hot Air"

>$ Sewer.Type   : chr  "Private" "Private" "Public" "Private"
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for example.

Comment: @StanZutt I am trying to...so sorry about syntax, R always doing this~

Comment: Post your data please. Try `dput()`.

Comment: @StanZutt I figured out, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem last night.
The problem is that I messed up the datafile, since i create a new data file named:

```
hp2 <- read_excel("Desktop/hw/424/hw1/housing_prices2.xlsx")
```

In addition, I messed up the Y variable as well, see

```
summary(lm(write ~ Fuel.Type.f, data = housing_prices2))
```

My Y variable actually is not write.